# Why do I get syntax errors when constructing selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is follow up question.

The first selector which is fully typed out finds the value all the others give a syntax error even though they "look" identical.

```
    $(".smoothie").on("mouseover", function(event) {
          // .. other code

            // first    
            value = $(".row_2.tuesday .e_1.current_Status .smoothie_Text").attr("value");
            alert(value);

            // second
            selector = "\'.row_2.tuesday .e_1.current_Status .smoothie_Text\'";
            alert(selector);
            value = $(selector).attr("value");

            //third
            value = $("\"." + row_Classes[0] + "." + row_Classes[1] + " ." + container_Classes[0] + "." + container_Classes[1] + " .smoothie_Text\"").attr("value");
            alert(value);
          //.. other code
}).svg({loadURL: '../_public/_icons/smoothie.svg'});
```

Could some one please advise what I am doing wrong.

**Edit**

Error from console is:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ' [Break On This Error]
>
> throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );

Which we know from yesterdays enquiries is from sizzle.

Comment: They are not identical, second and third selectors have surrounded by quotes. You shouldn't use quotes around selectors.

Comment: why are you escaping quotes in strings?

Comment: @tborychowski A better question is why the quotes are there at all. The third example does in fact legitimately require escaping of the quotes.

Comment: Ok I was getting in a mess thinking I needed the quotes to complete the selector on the basis that $("#someid .someclass").dosomething is the normal syntax so I was adding them in when constructing the selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your second and third strings contain quotes at the ends. Selectors are not supposed to contain quotes at the ends. It is that simple.

Comment: Yes looking at this for to long got in a mess. Couldn't see why. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

try it by removing `\'` , so it should be like as below

```
// second
selector = ".row_2.tuesday .e_1.current_Status .smoothie_Text";
```

there is no need of the `\'` in your selector code

Answer (score 0):

try remove slashes `\` and single quotes `'`

```
        selector = ".row_2.tuesday .e_1.current_Status .smoothie_Text";
        alert(selector);
        value = $(selector).attr("value");

        //third
        value = $(row_Classes[0] + "." + row_Classes[1] + " ." + container_Classes[0] + "." + container_Classes[1] + " .smoothie_Text").attr("value");
        alert(value);
```